# Robocopy for long paths with /mir switch changed destination to root and nuked machine

Tags: robocopy

My purpose was to copy files with long paths (+255 char) and spaces in the folder path from a computer to a server with an analogus folder already in place (needed to maintain folder structure). Below is an example of the script:

```
robocopy "c:\long path\with spaces" "\\servername\long path\with spaces" filename.html /MIR /R:5 /LOG+:\\server\logfolder /v /NP
```

The result was the below log and a complete deletion of the source machine. Any thoughts?

```
Source : c:\long path\with spaces
Dest : \
Files : filename.html
Options : /V /S /E /PURGE /MIR /NP /R:5 /W:30
```

I've been researching and have found no other situation. I'd absolutely love to avoid this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, robocopy is going to see the `"\\"` as an escape sequence, and you end up with a path that's just `\`.  you need to use `/"\servername\long path\with spaces\/"` for quoted UNC paths.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. I've been running in circles researching this with no luck! Do know of any documentation that I can reference for this issue?

Comment: the closest you can get to for documentation is http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html, it does mention not using a trailing \ as that is treated as an escape character... in the case of UNC, the \\ is escaped because the second \ appears before any other characters; this happens in PowerShell as well.